# Reinstall Windows XP using "Windows XP Service Pack 3 - ISO-9660 CD Image File"

Tags: windows, windows-xp, reinstall

I would like to reinstall Windows XP on my old computer.

I do not have the original setup disks, however there is a file on the Microsoft Download centre called "[Windows XP Service Pack 3 - ISO-9660 CD Image File](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=2fcde6ce-b5fb-4488-8c50-fe22559d164e)"

Could I burn this to a CD, and use it to reinstall XP by using the product key on a sticker on the old computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not a full version of Windows with SP3.

"This file is a CD image file for users who wish to create an update CD for Windows XP Service Pack 3" (from site)

Answer (score 1):

For the past few years, I've been using [this](http://www.tipandtrick.net/2008/download-unmodified-original-windows-xp-with-sp3-integrated-full-retail-and-vl-install-cd-iso-image-from-msdntechnet-plus-via-http-or-torrent/) site for installs. The ISO's linked are the original RTW (release to web) versions available to Technet and MSDN subscribers. They don't have viruses or anything.

If you don't want to trust anything on the dangerous internet even though I know these are clean, you can pay to subscribe to Technet or MSDN and download from there. Or if a friend or co-worker has older service pack cd's you can install it then tack on the needed SP's. Much more complex.

Comment: Do OEM keys work with those versions? I know they won't for Retail versions.

Comment: I tried the normal XP Pro SP3 and my OEM key worked just fine. Results may vary however.

Answer (score 0):

If you purchased the computer from the manufacturer, you can often buy replacement setup discs from them.  HP, Dell, and others all usually offer this.  Other than finding your old setup discs or purchasing a new disc & license, this is probably your only alternative.