# A link to a Windows XP Professional Service Pack 3 Disk?

Tags: windows-xp, sp3

Upon running `'SFC /SCANNOW'` I get a message to insert the Windows XP Pro SP3 disk.
I had previously never heard of a Windows XP pro Service Pack 3 disk, I though there was only one type of SP3 CD. After some research, I located a service pack 3 disk, so I downloaded it, and tried running the command again. It complained about the CD being for the wrong version of XP. I've searched google for ages trying to find the correct one, to no avail. So, my question is:

Does anyone have a link to download a 'Windows XP Pro SP3' disk, the requirements are:

- That it runs offline.
- That it comes in a .iso file
- That it is for Windows XP professional

By the way, I've already tried this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25129

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: if you run winver.exe what version does it say you're running?

Comment: Microsoft Windows Home Edition
Version 1.5 (Build 2600.xpsp_sp3_gdr.120504-1619 : Service Pack 3)

Comment: Related: [Reinstall Windows XP using “Windows XP Service Pack 3 - ISO-9660 CD Image File](http://superuser.com/questions/159075/reinstall-windows-xp-using-windows-xp-service-pack-3-iso-9660-cd-image-file)

Comment: @techie007 I don't want to reinstall windows, I need the disk to use spc

Comment: I pointed the second link out as related info, just to show that the SP3 CD you linked to isn't a full install disk (like Windows is asking you for), and for relational tracking sake. :)

Comment: Check out this MS article titled [Steps to take before you install Windows XP Service Pack 3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950717) which describe the many prerequisites to installing Windows XP SP3 as well as some troubleshooting tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's asking for a Windows disk that has SP3 integrated into it already; not just a SP3 CD.

You'll need create a new XP Install disk [with SP3 slip-streamed into it](http://www.google.ca/search?q=xp+slipstream+how+to).

Comment: Thanks :)

I suspect that this version of XP has infected system files :P (hence my trying to run sfc). Do you know where I can get a windows XP + sp3 disk?

Comment: oh, wait, I though it was taking the computer's host OS as the base for the new windows, not a windows install CD... thanks :)